# VS Code - multiple source files in one folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm learning C in VS Code and I want to find a way, if there is one, to create multiple source files in one folder to test my coding examples. Otherwise, I need to create a separate folder for each coding example and it's a bit annoying. Is there a way to do this by changing the configuration of the '.json' files?
Thanks.

Comment: correct me if wrong; but your requirement is :  a single folder, with single task configuration and all your .c files in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by having a task.json some thing as below:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++-10 build active file",
        "command": "/usr/local/bin/g++-10",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    }
]
}
```

This above task will build the .c file which is currently active in your vscode. Also, it will put your executable file in a single `build` folder. So you can have all your c/CPP files in a single source folder and all your executables will be lying in the `build` folder.

**P.S**: make sure to change the `command` according to whatever compiler you are using.